# python import class from different folder

Tags: python, import

my project has folders that are structured like this:

```
main
 -folder 1
  -file1.py
 -folder 2
  -file2.py
```

both file1 and file2 having classes.
when I try `from main.folder1.file1 import class1` it fails, saying "No module named main". What am I doing wrong and how should I import it?

Comment: Have you tried `from folder1.file1 import class1` ?

Comment: Have you created an empty `__init__.py` file in `main` and `main/folder1`? See the following for additional documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=packages#regular-packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to first create the module by including `__init__.py`
in the root directory which is same in the hierarchy of main folder and also create an `__init__.py` in other sub folders to make them accessible as modules.
Here is an example structure from the official documentation.Note how at each level there is `__init__.py` you have to include similarly.

```
package/
    __init__.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleX.py
        moduleY.py
    subpackage2/
        __init__.py
        moduleZ.py
    moduleA.py
```

your structure can be like below:

```
main/
    __init__.py
    folder1/
        __init__.py
        file1.py
    folder2/
        __init__.py
        file2.py
```

Then you can append the path to the module at the top  level like below.
You can have it in the `__init__.py` in the root directory.

> sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(**file**))))

Then try accessing like `from folder1.file1 import class1`.
This should resolve your problem.

To further understand your problem read about `modules` and how to include `relative imports` by referring [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Answer (score 0):

In python you have to declare each folder as a module by adding a file named `__init__.py` in each directory including the root. This file can be empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this if there are one level above.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'../folder1')
sys.path.insert(0,'../folder2')
import function1
import function2
....
```

Once you run the first 3 lines, you are adding those folders to the working directory. You can then import the functions within those files as if they are in the file already.

If the folders are in the same level, do this,

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'folder1')
sys.path.insert(0,'folder2')
import function1
import function2
....
```